# How to remove all plugins, posts, pages, and inactive themes in one line with wp-cli? WordPress bloatware removal

Tags: linux, command-line, php

Softaculous seems to always adds junk to the installs I don't want. Such as example posts, pages, plugins, and starter themes. How do I remove them all for a fresh start?

Comment: Or... Don't use Softaculous :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd love any improvements, or hopefully this helps someone.

```
wp post delete $(wp post list --post_type='post' --format=ids);wp post delete $(wp post list --post_type='page' --format=ids);wp plugin delete --all;wp theme delete $(wp theme list --status=inactive --field=name);wp widget delete $(wp widget list sidebar-1 --fields=id);wp widget delete $(wp widget list sidebar-2 --fields=id)
```

edit: added removal of default widgets in sidebar, all seems to work now!

Comment: Also, make sure you don't run this as root, at least it doesn't work for me. Rather $ su {user}  then execute this command in the root of whatever wordpress install you want to clear out junk items in the default wordpress install.